# iOS : MPMoviePlayerViewController / MPMoviePlayerController Zoom In by default?

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

Can `MPMoviePlayerViewController` zoom in by default when the phone is in portrait mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by zooming, you are referring to the `MPMovieScalingMode` then the answer is no, it does not do that by itself. You may however do it yourself by simply handling the device rotation (either within the wrapping viewController or by registering for the adequate notification).

For adjusting the scaling, simply set `MPMoviePlayerController`'s `scalingMode` property to the appropriate value.

See [the reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for possible values.